# solr highlighting in old and new versions

Tags: solr, highlighting

I am migrating a web site from an old version of solr (1.4.1) to the current release version (5.2.1) on a different machine and noticing some differences.

In the old version, I could get highlighting with a url like this:

http://localhost:8983/solr/select?indent=on&q=text:software/&start=0&rows=10&fl=id,score,title&wt=json&hl=on&hl.fragsize=200

In the new version, one thing that's different is I need to specify a collection. Another difference is that the new version gives an error if I put `text:` in front of the value of `q`.

So, taking into account those differences, I end up with a URL like this:

http://localhost:8983/solr/default/select?indent=on&q=software/&start=0&rows=10&fl=id,score,title&wt=json&hl=on&hl.snippets=1&hl.fl=%2a&hl.fragsize=200

That second URL does not give me highlighting fragments/snippets. That is to say, where the old URL would give something like this:

```
"highlighting":{
  "document0_id":{"text":["The <em>software</em> is awesome"]}}
```

The new URL gives something like this:

```
"highlighting":{
  "document0_id":{}}
```

What do I need to do to get highlighting fragments returned in solr 5.2.1?

[edited]

In addition, I tried selecting a single document by its id on both machines. On the old machine, a url like

http://localhost:8983/solr/select?wt=json&indent=true&q=id:thedocumentid

returns some JSON that includes a `text` field containing the full searchable text of the original HTML document. On the new machine a similar url (but one that includes the collection):

http://localhost:8983/solr/default/select?wt=json&indent=true&q=id:thedocumentid

...returns similar JSON that does **not** include the `text` field.

I note that searching returns the correct results; the problem is that on the new machine, the results do not include the highlighting fragments. 
So it seems like maybe the issue is that I need to specify that these documents have a text field when I index them; how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colleague (not tempted by the bounty) noticed that my `text` field had `stored="false"` in my schema.xml and suggsted changing it to `true`. That did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the first query you are specifically searching in the text field and in the second its not.
2. And in the second you have mentioned hl.fl which means "Specifies a list of fields to highlight. Accepts a comma- or space-delimited list of fields for which Solr should generate highlighted snippets. If left blank, highlights the defaultSearchField"

Try again by making the changes...

http://localhost:8983/solr/default/select?q=text:software&start=0&rows=10&fl=id,score,title&wt=json&hl=on&hl.fragsize=200

Comment: That returns: `{"responseHeader":{"status":400,"QTime":2,"params":{"hl.fragsize":"200","fl":"id,score,title","start":"0","q":"text:software","wt":"json","hl":"on","rows":"10"}},"error":{"msg":"undefined field text","code":400}}`

Comment: could you please share the schema.xml been used for your collection?

Comment: It's at https://gist.github.com/dtenenba/367ccf577651d953150a .
Note that this is my /etc/solr/conf/schema.xml; My collection does not seem to have its own schema.xml. I created it using `bin/solr create_core -c default`.